# Dynamic From FormArray newly added controls changes not propagated

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, formarray

Noticed a strange behavior with angular5 forms using the builder to construct a form which contains a form array needed to capture additional dynamic data, the form array values are only updated if

1. During creation initial form controls where added to form array `this.formBuilder.array(this.getRow())`
2. When the first initial control is touched

**Angular version 5.2.0
[Experimental/Sample Code Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkuqww)**

**Point 1/2 Addendum**

Changes appear to only be registered on components that are not dynamically added to FormArray

*Code where form array element is inclusive of initialization process*

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:[null],
      description:[null],
      hobbies:this.formBuilder.array([this.getRow()])
    });
  }

  getRow():FormGroup{
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      hobby:[null],
      description:[null]
    });
  }
```

[image]

though it is evident that additional controls where created, they are all empty

However as soon as the first element is touched *(noticed change from fishing to fishing4 and console output now has values of remaining dynamically added controls*), all new dynamic fields values are propagated

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you and, like you mentioned in your comment, the problem was that I was pushing the new controls on the .controls property of the form array.

So instead of

```
this.form.controls.xxx.controls.push(this.formBuilder.group(getGroup()));
```

you should go with

```
this.form.controls.xxx.push(this.formBuilder.group(getGroup()));
```

---

**Later edit:**
Navigating the nested forms using the `controls` property doesn't make for the safest Angular updates. If they decide that the property will no longer be named `controls` in a future update to Angular, you're going to need to change quite a bit of code.

So instead of my previous code:

```
this.form.controls.xxx.push(this.formBuilder.group(getGroup()));
```

you should use

```
this.form.get('xxx').push(this.formBuilder.group(getGroup()));
```

This makes your code cleaner and future proofs it in case of any breaking changes to the `controls` property.

Answer (score 0):

In your html change:

```
<form [formGroup]="form.controls.hobbies">
```

and

```
  <tr *ngFor="let hobby of form.get('hobbies').controls; let r=index;" [formGroupName]="r">
     <td><input type="text" formControlName="hobby"></td>
     <td><input type="text" formControlName="description"></td>
  </tr>
```

by:

```
<div formArrayName="hobbies">
    <div *ngFor="let hobby of form.get('hobbies').controls; let r=index;">
        <div [formGroupName]="r">
             <td><input type="text" formControlName="hobby"></td>
             <td><input type="text" formControlName="description"></td>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this article:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: I tried that earlier and effects are the same, further more I attempted to execute this.form.setControl("hobbies",(this.form.get("hobbies") as FormArray)); after creating the dynamic fields. Though after executing the code I can see dynamic fields, their values are only updated when the non dynamic control is updated. Similar implementation as that posted on scotch.io (https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/)

Comment: Yebo, I did resolve. Issue was that I was push into form controls not the for array group. For fix/working version follow link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkuqww